# Pycharm marks a string as error with <statement> or DELIMITER expected, got 'The'

Tags: pycharm

For the following statement, Pycharm shows the keyworkd 'The' as error with message I put in the subject:

```
string_something = "The text " + some_string_variable + " with more text here."
```

Any idea how to configure Pycharm to not show it as an error?

I'm using Pycharm 2018.1.3 (professional).

Update 06/14/18:
I could reproduce now with a slightly modified string. I think that Pycharm believes that it is some kind of query (SQL query?)

string_something = "It can be reproduce " + "**with**   **as**  here"

This is just one way of reproducing it (having with + 3 spaces + as).

One of the workarounds is use some synonym of with. Then Pycharm doesn't mark it as a string with error.

I think that  Pycharm is trying to guess the content of the string, and giving an error because it is misinterpreting it as something else.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the same error in my PC using pycharm professional version. Can you please provide some extra code lines ?

Comment: I can reproduce it with just 1 line. I copied the error line to a clean .py file, and Pycharm shows it as an error. I'm not sure what Pycharm is trying to do (would need to read the docs :-) but I found a workaround, by using a keyword other than 'with' . Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some SQL dialect configured in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | SQL Dialects**?